# Passing html element id to ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-class

I am a beginner with Angular and ui-router. I am trying to apply an active class for a tab in the header based on the current state name.

```
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="tab1" ng-class="navTabClass(this.id)">
            <a href="link1.html">Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li id="tab2" ng-class="navTabClass(this.id)">
            <a href="link2.html">Sales
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I have a function defined in the controller for determining the class by checking the tab id and current state name (after trimming out the the name for my parent views)

```
 `$scope.navTabClass = function(tabId) {
                            console.log(tabId);
                            var stateName = $state.current.name;
                            mainTab = stateName.split('.');
                            return (mainTab[1] === tabId) ? 'active' : 'passive';
                        }
```

I printed out the tabId received and it is always 'undefined'. Needless to say, the function always returns passive as the class name

How do I pass the id value correctly to the controlled function ?

Comment: can you set up a jsFiddle or plunker to replicate the issue?

Comment: are you trying to access the ID from the UI.Router parameter in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

ng-class expects an object, so

Try this instead:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li id="tab1" ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 'tab1'}" ng-click="changeTab('tab1')">
        <a href="link1.html">Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2" ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 'tab2'}" ng-click="changeTab('tab2')">
        <a href="link2.html">Sales
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then your JS would look like this:

```
$scope.changeTab = function(tabName){
    $scope.activeTab = tabName;
    console.log('tabName', tabName);
}
```

This would flip the state of your tabs

Comment: I was looking for an answer which will also work if we change the state (tab) by changing the URL. The above code will work only when the user clicks on a tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see that demo :

http://plnkr.co/edit/cyZPh5h1lIYykqrh8Igh?p=preview

you can use `ui-sref-active` directive more info you can find here

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

```
 <ul class="tabs">
    <li id="tab1" ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2" ui-sref-active="active">
      <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Please see my comment on EliteOctagon's answer